# django makemigrations for a different database that is not configured

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm working on a project that requires us to turn in mysql scripts of our database. Is there a way to tell Django to make MySql migrations instead of SqLite migrations, without configuring/connecting to a mysql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrations created by the `makemigrations` command are database agnostic, they can be run on any database.

You can use the [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) to show the SQL for a given migration. To generate SQL for MySQL, you would have to to add a MySQL database to your `DATABASES` setting. From a quick test, it looks like Django tries to connect to the MySQL server when you run the `showmigrations`. Therefore I don't think it will be possible to avoid configuring settings with a MySQL server, without diving deep into the Django internals.